# Batch renaming filenames between hyphens using bash

Tags: linux, bash, file-rename, batch-rename

I'm a student and I'm very new to bash, so any help is greatly appreciated!

I'm trying to rename a batch of files that look like this: local_date_1415+6556_0001.txt and local_date_1415+6556_0002.txt.

Example file name: uuw_07052006_1415+6556_0001.txt

I need the "1415+6556" section of each filename to have a 2M in front of it, like "2M1415+6556". About half the files in the folder already have the 2M, so I can't just search for the string and replace.

Is there a way to rename the batch of files using "_" as a delimiter so I could replace all the third sections entirely with the correct string?

I have the rename command on my machine, I'm just not sure how to use it here.

Comment: What rename command do you have, [rename](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename) or [rename](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/prename.1.html)?

Comment: Also, please show an example file name, what format does the "local date" have?

Comment: How do I check to see which one?

Comment: `man rename` maybe?

Comment: @choroba Thank you! `man rename` worked. I have the linux version: [rename] (http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename)

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not Linux technical support. Questions like this should be posted to unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. I'll make sure to do that in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your version of `rename`:

```
rename _ %   *_????+*.txt    # replace the first underscore with a percent
rename _ _2M *_????+*.txt    # add 2M after the second underscore
rename % _   *_2M????+*.txt  # return the first underscore back
```

Only works if your filenames don't contain `%`. If they do, pick a different character.

You can also write the loop yourself:

```
#! /bin/bash
for f in *_????+*.txt ; do
    before=${f%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]+*}
    after=${f#*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]}
    mv "$f" "$before"2M"$after"
done
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is half my files already have the 2M. Is there a way to program it, so it doesn't add the 2M if it's already there?

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't have enough points yet to plus one your response (hopefully I will later!). It worked perfectly. I had just one change on your last line in the first code: `rename % _ *_2M????+*.txt` `

Comment: @morepenguins: Great, you were able to fix it! :-)

Comment: Thanks! I am pretty proud of that. :-)